# Vercel: how to block the reading of important files

Tags: .htaccess, server, vercel

I would like to block some files, so that no user can access them. As files / folder css, js, sass ...

I found a part of vercel's documentation that talks about server configuration. However, I couldn't find any way to block these files.

It has the redirect, but it would be a lot of work.

this is my json so far

```
{
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": false,
    "rewrites": [
        { "source": "/inicio", "destination": "https://blog-semnome-9ui4b0xed-gobsruiz.vercel.app/html/index" },
        { "source": "/blog", "destination": "https://blog-semnome-9ui4b0xed-gobsruiz.vercel.app/html/blog" },
        { "source": "/contato", "destination": "https://blog-semnome-9ui4b0xed-gobsruiz.vercel.app/html/contact" },
        { "source": "/jogos-gratis-2021-pt1", "destination": "https://blog-semnome-9ui4b0xed-gobsruiz.vercel.app/html/posts/jogos-gratis-2021-pt1" }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know any way to block?

https://vercel.com/docs/configuration